# parseInt() check for NaN isn't working properly

Tags: javascript

I am working on a jQuery plugin and I need to make sure this value is a number, or a string with only a number.  So to do this I made the following code, where `val` is a variable that may or may not be a number.

```
if (typeof val !== 'number') {//if "val" isn't a number
    if (typeof val === 'string' && parseInt(val) !== NaN) {//see if "val" is a string with only a number
        val = parseInt(val);
    }
}
```

But for some reason, while testing, even if `val` is a string with text, it still returns `parseInt(val) !== NaN` as `true`.  I later tested with the Chrome console, and this is what I got:

[image: incorrect return]

As you can see, `'asf'` is `Not-a-Number`.  But wherever it returns `true`, it should return `false`, and wherever it returns `false`, it should return `true`.  You can also see that I tested to make sure `NaN` isn't actually a string.

[image: correct return]

Above you can see the return values are the same, but this time it is correct.

Am I missing something?  Or is there a different way I am supposed to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) ?

Comment: @Evilzebra  I did not know this existed.  Thank you!

Comment: The way to check it is `isNaN()` method

Comment: Also relevant, why [NaN !== NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

NaN is not something you can compare to.
you need to use :

`isNaN(parseInt('asf')) // true`

`isNaN(parseInt('123')) // false`

Comment: I wish your reputation grows fast with this simply answer. Awesome ! Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to check if a value is a number or not is to use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).